# RabbitMQ basic.return

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, easynetq

If I publish with confirmation(model.ConfirmSelect) AKA basic.ack and mandatory flag. Will I always get the basic.return event before the basic.ack event if the message was not delivered.

I want to add all basic.return messages to ConcurrentDictionary and after publish I'll check if the message is in the dicitonary I'll throw an exception, that no queue/route exists, and remove it, on error or success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will always receive the events in that order.

From the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html):

> ## When will messages be confirmed?
>
> For unroutable messages, the broker will issue a confirm once the exchange verifies a message won't route to any queue (returns an empty list of queues). ***If the message is also published as mandatory, the basic.return is sent to the client before basic.ack***. The same is true for negative acknowledgements (basic.nack).